# jquery toggle visibility if has class

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've collected all my portfolio items into an array as seen here.

```
function SetPortfolioItems(filter) {
    items = $( ".portfolio-item" ); 

    items.toggle("slow");
}
```

The function parameter is a string class name for example "Print". What I want to do is hide the portfolio items which don't have the class 'filter' and the ones that do, make them visible.

Comment: Have you try `hasClass()` in `JQuery` ? https://api.jquery.com/hasclass/ @JokerMartini

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your question:

> What I want to do is hide the portfolio items which don't have the class 'filter' and the ones that do, make them visible.

You can make this:

```js
function SetPortfolioItems(filter) {
    var str = filter.toLowerCase();

    var invalidItems = $( ".portfolio-item:not(."+str+")"); 
    invalidItems.hide("slow");

    var validItems = $( ".portfolio-item." + str ); 
    validItems.show("slow");
}

SetPortfolioItems('filter');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="portfolio-item">item 1</div>
<div class="portfolio-item filter">item 2</div>
<div class="portfolio-item">item 3</div>
<div class="portfolio-item filter">item 4</div>
<div class="portfolio-item">item 5</div>
<div class="portfolio-item">item 6</div>
```

Comment: How can i make it ignore case sensitivity?

Comment: CSS is case sensitive. What do you need?

Comment: Maybe you can write all your css in lowercase, and then in the js function add the `filter.toLowercase()` method, by this mode all your code will be in lowercase and you don't care about case sensitive

Comment: If this solves your question please, upvote / check as correct answer . Thank you !

Comment: i will, i can't mark it for 2 more minutes. silly SO

Answer (score 0):

Use jQuery [**`not()`**](http://api.jquery.com/not/) function.

```
function SetPortfolioItems(filter) {
    items = $( ".portfolio-item" ); 
    items.not('.' + filter).hide("slow");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `hasClass` by jQuery :

[jQuery Docs](https://api.jquery.com/hasclass/)

```
function SetPortfolioItems(filter) {
    items = $( ".portfolio-item" ); 

    if (items.hasClass(filter)) {
        ...
    } else {
        ...   
    }
}
```

Comment: It doesn't work like this example. If you have a collection of items you need to iterate through them. I don't know why this have an upvote, but this don't works with that code